# Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, npm, undefined, carousel

I have a project using VueJS. I have a problem. I want to use owl.carousel. I installed it via this command

```
 npm install --save owl.carousel
```

and I imported it as follows:

```
<script>
import jQuery from 'jquery'
let $ = jQuery
import 'owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css';
import 'owl.carousel';
export default {
    name: "SlideShow"
}
</script>
```

And template:

```
<template>
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div> Your Content </div>
    <div> Your Content </div>
    <div> Your Content </div>
    <div> Your Content </div>
    <div> Your Content </div>
    <div> Your Content </div>
    <div> Your Content </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Then I have an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined.

Please help me resolve this problem. Thank a lot!!!

Comment: I imported jquery: 'import jQuery from 'jquery'
    let $ = jQuery'

Comment: could you share package.json content?

Comment: You shouldn't use jQuery plugins with Vue. There is a Vue wrapper for owl carousel: https://github.com/93gaurav93/v-owl-carousel or https://ssense.github.io/vue-carousel/

Answer (score 0):

hai import jquery like this format

`import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
 window['jQuery'] = jQuery;`

Answer (score 0):

It is because jQuery is missing, you can follow @goarun12 instruction, or directly add the script import in your HTML

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As you want, please mark your question as solved

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort the order of the script tags according to the sorted bootstrap

[image]